# How can I make Maya or Blender model work with mecanim?

Tags: unity, blender, maya, mecanim

I'm working on a simple game project, where I need a stick figure. Due to being stubborn and the desire to learn a new skill, I want to make the stick figure myself! I have followed several tutorials in both Maya and blender. For Maya, I'm using the student version. I have my stick figure rigged within Maya and blender, both utilizing their respective bone tools. I can manipulate their limbs well, enough. However, I can't seem to get the models to work with Mecanim.

I have the Kinect adapter for the PC and would like to be able to use it to create the animations utilizing a tool such as the Kinect v2 mocap animator.

How I can get my model to work with Kinect based mocap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, read the documentation on preparing your model for mecanim: [Preparing your own character](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preparingacharacterfromscratch.html) and watch the introduction videos for mecanim on Unity's website [Unity Animation Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation).

I'm not sure how to make it work with Kinect, but probably something along the lines of remapping the values you get from Kinect onto the skeletal bones of your character.